# Elastic Search client for Python index name with cluster?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Im using Python Elastic Search client for my project to query es data.

I have index pattern `content:log_my` that I want to query, however, when i execute

```
log_result = self.es.search(index='content:log_my', query=self.get_query(), doc_type='example')
```

it result in the `:` in encoded

```
GET https://url_here/content%3Alog_my/example/_search [status:N/A request:10.025s]
```

Can I know how to fix on this? Thanks, I'm new on Python.

Answer (score 1):

Since ES 7.0 onwards, : is not allowed as well. You might want to revert to old version of elasticsearch.

For my information - https://discuss.elastic.co/t/index-name-type-name-and-field-name-rules/133039/2